# Electron: jQuery is not defined (for an EXTERNAL site)

Tags: jquery, electron

I know this question has been answered time and time again, but the answers assumed one could change code of rendered page. In my case, I have to redirect to an external public SSO site for authentication which happens to use jQuery and causes this:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Note again: I do not have the ability to change ANYTHING in that external site.

Comment: can you please show how you are posting your data to other site. And i think problem is st your end not on other side. (the message you shown is telling that error is at your code )

Comment: The error appears upon navigating to an external authentication website that's using jQuery. For now I have disabled node integration and it works. I'm not using jQuery in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jquery on your side then remove the script for it. The prb is on your side not on the other side.

If you use jquery on your side this is what I found helpful:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that need to use node integration and don't have the option to modify the page html, the method from the Electron [FAQ](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron) can be applied in a preload script instead:

```
const path = require('path');

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
})
```

Where `preload.js` just contains the lines from the FAQ:

```
window.nodeRequire = require;
delete window.require;
delete window.exports;
delete window.module;
```